# Curly brace vs Square bracket

Tags: grails, groovy

I can't figure out what's the difference between Curly brace and Square bracket in Groovy/Grails
Example :

```
[bookInstanceList:Book.list()]
```

and :

```
{
    subject blank: false
    content blank: false, maxSize: 2000
}
```

can any one help me please?
Thank you

Comment: The first is a `List` and the second is a `closure`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, isn't a closure supposed to "do some operations" ?

Comment: But what is the real question? These two are totally different things. One is how you pass data from C to View and other one is a set of constraints in Domain.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks that was just an example, my question is what's the difference between the name/value paires inside Curly braces and inside Square brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the first is a `Map` and the second is a `closure`.

They aren't the same or similar in any way. You seem to be confused because you assume the `closure` is some type of name value pair. Which, in this case, it would appear to be because of the constraints DSL.

To further understand how this `closure` is processed you would need to dig deeper into the constraints DSL and see how it uses such things as missing methods and missing properties. It's not a simple subject to explain briefly.

Comment: I think you have to edit your comment, you've written "List" instead of "Map"

Comment: Correct, but I can't edit my comment. I need more coffee this morning ;)

Comment: Ok :) we all do ^^

Answer (score 4):

**Groovy List and Map :**

First one is Map.
[] (Square bracket) in groovy is used for making list or map.

**Example of List:**

- [] - An empty list
- [1,2,3,4] – A list of integer values
- [‘Angular’, ‘Groovy’, ‘Java’] – A list of Strings
- [1, 2, [3, 4], 5] – A nested list

**Example of Map:**

- [ : ] – An Empty map.
- [key: "value"] - Map with key and values

**Groovy Closure :**

The second one is groovy DSL. We can use multiple strategies to create DSL but in Grails domain constraint blocks used groovy closures for this. You can find more details about DSL [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html) and closures [here](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html).